# Are there stable Objective-C implementations of the Mersenne Twister algorithm for randomness?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, random

I'd really love to use [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) as alternative to arc4random. So to make my life not too hard it would be great if there was an implementation of this in Objective-C which I can simply add to my project.

So I searched and found this: [Mersenne Twister in Objective-C](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1083103)

Unfortunately, the author writes in the post:

> I am not exactely sure if the implementation is 100% correct with respect to the "-0.5" that I added.

I can't verify if it's correct or not, but of course it would be stupid to use a third party implementation rather than the original if the "translator" isn't sure about it's correctness.

Maybe I should just go with the C implementation and write an Objective-C interface to access the functions? Did anyone else do exactly this?

Comment: Can we please stop tagging objective-c questions as C questions? =(

Comment: Why? The algorithm is implemented originally in C, and maybe I'll have to deal with C.

Comment: i agree with Conrad, that it's specific to objc. `Why?` because it creates a lot of noise for people who aren't interested or familiar enough with objc to answer your question. c happens to be more 'popular' than objc; the languages are different while the answer you're seeking is specific to objc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Objective C is a pure superset of ANSI C.  So, if you have a C implementation that fits your requirements, just use that.  You could wrap the C function in an Obj C method if needed for syntactical reasons.